# What is the use of [^\n]?(in C)

Tags: c

I  have tried finding it on google, found nothing exact.
tried running it on codeblocks still not able to understand it's use?
I saw it with scanf() somewhere something like

```
scanf("%s[^\n]", &someStringName) ;
```

PS: New to programming

Comment: post the code , what exactly you trying to do

Comment: It's used on `scanf` to get the string until the end of line, not stopping at spaces.

Comment: Please update the question to show at least the line of code containing this. `[^\n]` by itself doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've almost certainly seen that sequence within a format string used by the `fscanf` family of functions.

From the ISO C standard (C11), slightly adjusted for readability:

> `[` matches a nonempty sequence of characters from a set of expected characters (the scanset).
>
> The conversion specifier includes all subsequent characters in the format string, up to and including the matching right bracket `]`.
>
> The characters between the brackets (the scanlist) compose the scanset, unless the character after the left bracket is a circumflex `^`, in which case the scanset contains all characters that do *not* appear in the scanlist between the circumflex and the right bracket.

The string `[^\n]` is therefore a conversion specifier which means any number of characters that are not a newline character.

In other words, it's a way to read a string all the way to the end of the line, since `%s` will stop on white space. So, if you were to input `Pax Diablo` as your name, `scanf("%s", buffer)` would only give you `Pax` whereas `scanf("[^\n]", buffer)` would give you the entire input line `Pax Diablo`.

Note that it *doesn't* read the newline itself, this is left in the input stream for the next read operation.